# Get links of type tested by associated with a user story

Tags: c#-4.0

How to get the links of type "Tested By " associated with a user story in tfs using c#.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried and what has not worked?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a work item's link you need:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection col = new TfsTeamProjectCollection("https://myorg.visualstudio.com");
WorkItemStore store = new WorkItemStore(col);
WorkItem wi = store.GetWorkItem(1234);
foreach (Link item in wi.Links)
{
Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("link for {0} of type {1}", wi.Id, item.GetType().Name), "LinkMigrationContext");
}
```

If you load a work item that has the link type that you are looking for you will be able to see the values and data that you are looking for.

Comment: But all the linksr are of type related. So then how to distinguish tested by links

Comment: Convert the link to a related link and you should get that data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below C# sample code to retrieve the `Tested By` links which associated with a specific work item:

Install the Nuget package [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClien](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/)t

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models;

namespace RetrieveTestedByLinks
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int id = 1; //specify the work item ID here

            var myCredentials = new VssClientCredentials();
            var connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(@"http://tfs2017-5044:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"), myCredentials);
            WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

            WorkItem workitem = workItemTrackingClient.GetWorkItemAsync(id, expand: WorkItemExpand.Relations).Result;

            Console.WriteLine("WorkItem ID: {0}", workitem.Id);

            Console.WriteLine("TestedBy Links: ");
            foreach (var relation in workitem.Relations)
            {

                if (relation.Rel == "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.TestedBy-Forward")
                    Console.WriteLine(relation.Url);

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Besides, if PowerShell is an option, then you can use below sample with the REST API to get the links of type "`Tested By` " associated with a work item:

```
Param(
   [string]$collectionurl = "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection",
   [string]$workitemid = "74",
   [string]$user = "username",
   [string]$token = "password"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

#Get workitem relateions
$baseUrl = "$collectionurl/_apis/wit/workitems/$($workitemid)?"+"$"+"expand=all"            
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

$relations = $response.relations | where {$_.rel -like '*TestedBy*'} 

#Retrieve the links in a loop
$relationob = @()
foreach ($rel in $relations){

$customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
          "Rel" = $rel.rel
          "url" = $rel.url
        } 

    $relationob += $customObject
}

$relationob | Select `
                Rel,
                url  #|export-csv -Path C:\test\Links.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]

Comment: @SainuThaha Have you resolved the issue by above answer? any update?